# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest' - React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I receive the following error when try to build React Native project in Android. 
Workarounds like: 1. "tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"" in Manifest.XML and android.useAndroidX=true, android.enableJetifier=true does not work

```
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED /Users/infinitesolution/Desktop/Infinite-Master/Projects/ReactNative/Ruci/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

The dependencies I used

```
"dependencies": {
    "lottie-react-native": "^2.6.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native-cardview": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-complete-flatlist": "^1.1.34",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^6.0.3",
    "react-native-headroom": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-mail": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-share": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.0"
  },
```

Kindly add any possible workarounds for this issue

Answer (score 3):

Have faced this issue for the past two days. Lots of other answers mention using `react-native-device-info` to update version. But it doesn't work on my case.

The main cause is due to google play services and firebase update [Refer here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) which cause React native build failed.

I had made the build successful at last and here I am sharing the [gist link](https://gist.github.com/nadesh-git/908b9714f9c7f20b66dfb13b49ba346a)

Changed the following list of files as mentioned in the above gist link,

```
android/build.gradle:
build.gradle:
gradle.properties:
package.json
gradle-wrapper.properties
```

And finally used this package

```
npm i jetifier && npx jetify
```

Once done, at last run

```
react-native run-android
```

And made the build successful

Tips: use `./gradlew clean` before trying the fix. Hope it helps!

Comment: THANK YOU. I don't use device-info. Fast-image caused me issue after these steps. So I removed fast-image then it worked. .

Answer (score 0):

Just added in gradle.properties:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

And run `npm i jetifier && npx jetify` then `react-native run-android` and it worked for me :)

Comment: Jetifier is deprecated now. Not working